# Motorola 68k Memory System: Ram vs Rom

Tags: ram, memory-address, microprocessors, rom

I have to fill in the blanks for a 2 4mb RAM chip and 2 64kb ROM chip. I don't understand how to do it. Any type of input on it would help.

```
         | Starting Address (Binary)       | Starting Add. (Hex)| Ending  Add. (Hex)|
4mb RAM1 | 0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000 |     00 00 00       |                   |
4mb RAM2 |                                 |                    |                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
64kbROM1 | 1010 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000 |     A0 00 00       |                   |
64kbROM2 |                                 |                    |                   |
```

I think that for RAM 1  the ending address is FF FF FF. But I do not know where to start with the next starting binary address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - this is really just simple arithmetic with hex and binary. I'll get you started - see if you can fill in the rest...

```
          | Starting Address (Binary)     | Starting Add. (Hex)| Ending  Add. (Hex)|
4MB  RAM1 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |     00 00 00       |     3F FF FF      |
4MB  RAM2 | 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |     40 00 00       |                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
64kB ROM1 | 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |     A0 00 00       |                   |
64kB ROM2 |                               |                    |                   |
```

A useful quantity to remember is 1 MB == 100000 in hexadecimal.

Also note that the unit for byte is `B` (upper case), mega is `M` (upper case) and kilo is `k` (lower case). So it's `kB` for kilobytes, and `MB` for megabytes. If you think this is pedantic then note that lower case `m` means "milli", which is 1/1000th of a unit - I doubt that your system has 4 millibyte RAM modules!

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you for the guidance, I figured it all out now